# Will the L'Hopital's Rule work here, when it agrees with the derivation of the rule as I know it?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, indeterminate-forms

Say I have to find the limit for:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

Such that $$g(a)=0≠f(a)$$

Multiplying the numerator and denominator by $g(x)$, I get$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{g(x)^2}$$ and I get the indeterminate form $\frac 00$. So can I use the L'Hopital's Rule to find the limit here?

From [3B1B's video about L'Hopital's Rule at time stamp 14:30](https://youtu.be/kfF40MiS7zA), the rule works as the value of the numerator graph and denominator graph at given value which $x$ approaches is $0$, so I can just divide their derivatives. So will the L'Hopital's Rule work here, considering I can just derive the rule from such arrangement of the graphs?

Comment: Your initial factorization must be wrong (the numerator is $x^3+4x$, not $x^3-4x$). The limit is undefined.

Comment: @GregMartin ah, I'll edit this question to get a better example. thanks for pointing out

Comment: Edited the question for a more generalized case.

Comment: Yes, it will work here. Why not?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos because I'm originally solving for a function which is not the indeterminate form $\frac 00$, and my doubt was particularly fuelled by my teacher who said that I can't solve such questions this way, as it apparently won't work for some reason

Comment: @AltercatingCurrent Post your original function then we can explain this specific case. Very general explanations don't really help you, I think.

Comment: @callculus42 my original function was a case where limit doesn't exist, so I don't think that's a good example?

Comment: The transformed problem is $\lim \frac{f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)}{2g(x)g'(x)} = \lim \frac{f(x)}{2g(x)} + \lim \frac{f'(x)}{2g'(x)}$, assuming these limits exist. Fine, but what has been gained?

Comment: In summary, you may be able to do it, but you literally gain nothing. The derivative in the denominator is still $0$ at the point, so the limit still has the same issues, and if you break it up and cancel the derivative you just get back to your original limit. Much ado for nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say I have to find the limit for:
> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
> Such that $$g(a)=0≠f(a)$$

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both continuous at $x=a$, then the situation has to be game over.  That is, the limit must be $\pm \infty$.

This means that it does not matter what creative steps you attempt, with or without L'Hopital's rule.  Creativity won't alter that the limit must be $\pm \infty$.

The reason is that under the assumption that both functions are continuous, you have $g(x)$ approaching $0$ and $f(x)$ approaching some non-zero number, as $x$ approaches $a$.

---

Thanks to Greg Martin and Arturo Magidin for indicating an oversight in my answer.  As they have indicated, I overlooked that rather than the limit being $\pm \infty$ another possibility is that the limit might not exist.

See the comments following this answer, including the comment of Torsten Schoeneberg, which discusses the possibility of $f$ and/or $g$ not being continuous at $x=a$.

Comment: More precisely, each one-sided limit is usually $\pm\infty$, while the two-sided limit typically doesn't have this behaviour.

Comment: The limit may fail to exist, and not be either $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: @GregMartin That's also not true. Take a $g$ that oscilates around $0$, say $x\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for the assist.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the assist.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg L'hopital (the rule that the limit equals $\lim f'(x)/g'(x)$ ) could be applicable... The rule does not require continuity at $a$ when stated in its standard form.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am confused.  Doesn't $f$ have to be continuous at $x=a$ for $f'(a)$ to exist?  Similarly, doesn't $g$ have to be continuous at $x=a$ for $g'(a)$ to exist?

Comment: @user2661923 There is a version of the rule that only requires $f$ and $g$ to be differentiable in a neighborhood of $a$ with $g'(x)\neq 0$ there, and says that $\lim f/g = \lim f'/g'$. That is what the rule *actually* is originally, with the $f'(a)/g'(a)$ version being a corollary when the derivatives are continuous. See the description in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the explanation.  That clears up my confusion.